# Selector not called on touch of UIButton

Tags: swift, apple-tv

I have created the `UIButton` programmatically and set the method to call when user touch on it using remote control. Below is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,VLCMediaPlayerDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnClick: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var clickBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var zoomBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoutBtn: UIButton!

    var movieView: UIView! // Add VLC Player on movieView
    var mediaPlayer: VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer() // VLC Media Player
    var PlayButton = UIButton()
    var isZoom:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(68/255.0), green: CGFloat(117/255.0), blue: CGFloat(196/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))

        self.movieView = UIView()
        self.movieView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.movieView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.minX + 400, y: self.view.frame.minY, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 800, height: self.view.frame.height/2)
        self.view.addSubview(self.movieView)
        mediaPlayer.delegate = self
        mediaPlayer.drawable = self.movieView
        let url = "http://192.168.1.34:8852/out.ts"
        let urls = URL(string: url)
        let media = VLCMedia(url: urls!)
        mediaPlayer.media = media
        mediaPlayer.rate = 0
       // mediaPlayer.play()
        self.playButtonTapped(sender: mediaPlayer)

        PlayButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        PlayButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        PlayButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX - 100, y: self.view.frame.midY - 300, width: 200, height: 86) //midY-20
        PlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
      //  PlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause-button.png"/*"Pause-1.png"*/), for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(PlayButton)
       // self.view.bringSubview(toFront: PlayButton)
       // self.view.sendSubview(toBack: mediaPlayer.drawable as! UIView)
    }

    //The target function
    @objc func pressButton(){
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

The issue is `pressButton` method never get called.

Comment: So far I am unable to reproduce it. Are you sure that the button has been tapped? (if you tried to little long tap, you should see it highlighted).

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you for reply. button gets highlighted but method never get call. I am able to reproduce in my project.

Comment: Could you please add the full implementation for the view controller?

Comment: @Ahmad i have posted the code of my view controller.

Comment: isn't `playBtn` different from `PlayButton`? Are you sure you are tapping the right button?

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes. both are different and i am sure i am tapping the right button.

Comment: Still unreproducible... You might need to make sure that you are tapping `PlayButton`, not another button by mistake.

Comment: What does `self.playButtonTapped(sender: mediaPlayer)` do?

Comment: @Ahmad i am sure. Because i have checked it more than 5 times.

Comment: @Carpsen90 it is different method i have commented out the code of it.

Comment: Maybe your mediaPlayer hangs the app. What happens if you comment out all code related to mediaPlayer?

Comment: @cyanide Even if i comment out the code of mediaPlayer. Still PlayButton method never get call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was with ".touchUpInside" on tvOS, since that doesn't do what we might expect: we need to use ".PrimaryActionTriggered" instead.

Thank you all for your support.